# resharper: unwrap long string declaration

Tags: c#, resharper

Can resharper convert this:

```
var str = "gjkldfhgiodfh hg jkfgh jkhjhklfhfhkl jkghj´kl fjgfhjklgfh fkhgfkl";
```

Into this:

```
var str = @"gjkldfhgiodfh 
                hg jkfgh jkhjhkl
                fhfhkl jkghj´kl fjgfhjklgfh fkhgfkl";
```

I have looked over options in `Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping` at Wrap Long Lines (it's unchecked) and Keep Existing Line Breaks (it's unchecked) but these settings won't help me in this situation.

I have the Ultimate version (2016.2.2).

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it can't.

And that's mainly because what you suggest is not simply some nice formatting, but a complete change of content.

When adding a '@' before a string, everything that follows, including newlines, tabs and spaces, will be the content of that string. If you use that string, all content, including the newlines, tabs and spaces will be used as well.

Just try it with a Console.WriteLine:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = @"gjkldfhgiodfh 
                    hg jkfgh jkhjhkl
                    fhfhkl jkghj´kl fjgfhjklgfh fkhgfkl";

        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
> gjkldfhgiodfh 
>                     hg jkfgh jkhjhkl
>                     fhfhkl jkghj´kl fjgfhjklgfh fkhgfkl
```

And that's most probably not what you want.

Comment: what about converting var str = "abcdefgh" into var str = "abcd" + "efgh" on two lines?

Comment: @BudaGavril That might be possible, but I'm guessing you'd have to write a custom rule.

Comment: @juharr it seems that resharper is already doing this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Splitting_Lines_with_String_Literals.html

Comment: @BudaGavril. Nice one, never noticed that behavior, but it does work!

Comment: me neither. It's a nice feature.

Comment: @BudaGavril Yeah, but I thought you wanted something that would process a code file and make the line brakes for you.

Comment: This would be ideal, but I have to write a custom rule and it's not a simple task to do this in 1-2 hours...